# Struggling to pass props through navigation, I believe it has something to do with my AysncyStorage set multiple

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I'm trying to pass some values into another screen, it worked the first time when I tried it with one value, using `async` storage set for a single item, however, now I am trying it with multiple and it keeps crashing every time I press the item I want to get the data from.

Storing the data when I press on an item from a FlatList

```js
fetchOnPressOpacity = async item => {
  this.state.totalCalories += item.food.nutrients.ENERC_KCAL;
  this.state.totalFat += item.food.nutrients.FAT;
  this.state.totalCarbs += item.food.nutrients.CHOCDF;
  this.state.totalProtein += item.food.nutrients.PROCNT;

  const firstPair = ["totalCalories", JSON.stringify(this.state.totalCalories)];
  const secondPair = ["totalCarbs", JSON.stringify(this.state.totalCarbs)];
  const thirdPair = ["totalProtein", JSON.stringify(this.state.totalProtein)];
  const fourthPair = ["totalFat", JSON.stringify(this.state.totalFat)];

  try {
    this.setState({});

    await AsyncStorage.multiSet(firstPair, secondPair, thirdPair, fourthPair);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

`getData()` method, I am not too sure how to store the data:

```js
getData = async () => {
  try {
    const values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet([
      "totalCalories",
      "totalCarbs",
      "totalProtein",
      "totalFat"
    ]);
  } catch (e) {
    // read error
  }
  console.log(values);
};
```

So, right now my main problem is that the application crashes when I press an item.
I get the below error, but do not think this is the issue.

> VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or
> id property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor.

I am also able to write to the console the value before the app crashes.

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```
var items = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]
AsyncStorage.setItem("DATA_KEY", JSON.stringify(items))
// or
AsyncStorage.multiSet(items, () => {
//to do something
});
```

For your code

```
var items = [firstPair, secondPair, thirdPair, fourthPair];
AsyncStorage.setItem("DATA_KEY", JSON.stringify(items))
```

Get data

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(["key1", "key2"]).then(response => {
//to do something
})
```

Comment: When i console log the response, I get the following: Array [
    "key1",
    null,
  ],
  Array [
    "key2",
    null,
  ],

Answer (score 0):

Not really a fix to your code but if it's just to pass data to another screen, you could consider to pass data with navigation.

like:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
navigation.navigate('YourNextScreen',
     {
       totalCalories: this.state.totalCalories,
       totalCarbs: this.state.totalCarbs,
       totalProtein: this.state.totalProtein,
       totalFat: this.state.totalFat,
     });
```

and retrieve them in:

```
const {
    totalCalories,
    totalCarbs,
    totalProtein,
    totalFat
} = this.props.route.params;
```

in case you don't want to specifically save those data for later...

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/